Show that if $p<q$ then $\mathscr{P}_q(\Omega) \subseteq \mathscr{P}_p(\Omega)$.

Given the subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Let us define
$$\mathscr{P}_p(\Omega):=\left\{\mu \in \mathscr{P}(\Omega): \int_{\Omega}|x|^p \mathrm{~d} \mu<+\infty\right\},$$
where $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ is probability space and $\mu$ is a measure. Show that if $p<q$ then $\mathscr{P}_q(\Omega) \subset \mathscr{P}_p(\Omega)$.

My attempt: I tried to use the Hölder's inequality for $f = \vert x \vert^q$ and $g=1$ but I failed since $p/q < 1$.

The inclusion should be $\mathscr{P}_q(\Omega) \subset \mathscr{P}_p(\Omega)$.
In order to prove that, we can just split the integral into two: denote $\Omega_1=\Omega\cap \{x:|x|<1\}$ and $\Omega_2=\Omega\setminus \Omega_1$. Then, $$\int_{\Omega}|x|^p \mathrm{~d} \mu=\int_{\substack{\Omega_1}}|x|^p \mathrm{~d} \mu+\int_{\substack{\Omega_2}}|x|^p \mathrm{~d} \mu\leq \mu(\Omega_1)+\int_{\substack{\Omega_2}}|x|^q \mathrm{~d} \mu<\infty$$
